# Does $\prod_{k=3}^{\infty}\cos\frac{2\pi}{n!}$ have a closed-form solution?

Tags: products, infinite-product

How to compute this please?
$$\prod_{k=3}^{\infty}\cos\frac{2\pi}{k!}$$

I just know it is convergent.

Comment: @Dahaka Convergence is obvious.

Comment: @Dahaka Thank you. I tried $e^{i\theta}$, but I really do not know how to operate.

Comment: The product of real parts is not the real part of the product.

Comment: @Dahaka, Sam Street's is correct here, and it invalidates your argument.  However, your argument can be salvaged; it just needs a double sum.

Comment: @Dahaka For convergence, notice $\displaystyle\;\cos\frac{2\pi}{k!} = 1 + O\left(\frac{1}{(k!)^2}\right)$ and
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|  < \infty \iff 
\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty (1+a_k) \text{ converges absolutely }\implies \prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty (1+a_k)\text{ converges }$$

Comment: Do you consider the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n!^{2m}}$ (the first of them being related to Bessel functions) as *elementary* constants? In such a case you may simply exploit the fact that the Maclaurin series of $\log\cos$ has well-known coefficients.

Comment: @Dahaka Thank you, but I think $\prod_{k=3}^{\infty}\Re e^{\frac{2i\pi}{k!}} \neq \Re\prod_{k=3}^{\infty}e^{\frac{2i\pi}{k!}}$, because $i \cdot i = -1$ is part of $\Re$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: `In such a case you may simply exploit the fact that the Maclaurin series of $\log\cos x$ has well-known coefficients.` Which are? To me it seems as if they are completely random...At least the nominator.

Comment: @Diger: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TangentNumber.html

Comment: The value is $0.4822822840083255$. ISC found nothing.

Comment: @achillehui also $\cos(2\pi/k!)\in (0,1)$ for $k\ge 3$ so $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\left|\prod_{k=3}^m\cos(2\pi/k!)\right|\le 1$$

Comment: It might be worth noticing that
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \prod_{k=3}^{N+2} \cos \frac{2\pi}{k!} = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2^N} \sum_{(\sigma_3,...,\sigma_{N+2})\in \left\{+,-\right\}^N} \exp\left(\sum_{k=3}^{N+2} \sigma_k \, \frac{2\pi i}{k!}\right) \, .
$$